# Show the categories whether or not, it has threads

Tags: c#, sql, select, join

I'm trying to make an SQL query, that shows the categories as well as a count for how many threads are in the category.

This is what I got:

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id, COUNT(*) 
AS 'threadCount' FROM threads 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id
```

It kinda works, however, the result in threadCount will always be greater or equal to 1, even if there are no threads in there.

[image]

As you can see in this image above, every category seems to have a thread attached to it. But the thing is, only 'Category 1' has threads, all other Categories have 0 threads attached, so they should display 0 instead of 1.

Comment: This is because you have `Right outer join` to show and the categories that are not connected to Threads. If you remove the OUTER then you see only the categories that are connected with threads, If you like to keep the empty ones... need to make it a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Outer` on the join is include all the categories, even the one that are not connected with any thread, so that's why you have at least 1.

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id, COUNT(*) 
AS 'threadCount' FROM threads 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id
```

I will make it as,

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM threads WHERE 
      categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id) AS 'threadCount' 
FROM categories
```

where I direct count the threads for each category, with out connect them.

Comment: That's a very good point, and seems like a good way to do it. It did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since you are doing right outer join null is also counted as 1 when you don't have corresponding threads. Run your query as following to see what I have meant

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id
AS 'threadCount' FROM threads 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
```

Or you can exclude null counted as 1 by changing query like this,

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id, COUNT(threads.thread_category_id) 
AS 'threadCount' FROM threads 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories 
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id
```